# Passing entire tag in Javascript as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, parameters, webforms

I have a function in jQuery done like this:

```
  $('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').change(function () {
          var l = document.getElementById('popap');
          l.click();
         readURL(this);
      });
```

And here is the readURL function:

```
function readURL(input) {
          if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function (e) {
                  $('#before').attr('src', e.target.result);
              }

              reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
          }
      }
```

As you can see on the change event I'm passing a this as a parameter to the readURL function and then accessing it's properties inside the readURL function.

My question is, how would I be able to do the same if this event was triggered on the click of a button? Only this time I need to pass into the readURL function what was selected on the file upload element. I've tried something like following:

```
  $('#<%=btnEdit.ClientID%>').click(function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var l = document.getElementById('popap');
                  l.click();
                  readURL(document.getElementById("FileUpload1"));
              });
```

But this doesn't do anything really, the picture isn't shown at all... ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The actual ID, as you correctly coded your first code sample, is *not* "FileUpload1" - it's `<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>`. You have to extract the actual ID from ASP and use that, because that's the actual ID used in the markup that the browser sees.

Comment: yeah that was the issue, thanks a lot!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ObjectCreateURL, it's faster...

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var url = Object.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
    $('#before').attr('src', url);
  }
}
```